# Tesseract based OCR app shows failed to read bitmap error

Tags: android, bitmap, ocr, tesseract

I am developing an Android Application in which i would like to capture a image and extract text from that .I used tessaract library. I put a image  in drawable folder and checked it works fine but when it comes to scanning a captured image an application closing.Here is my code

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
           EditText editText;
           ImageView imageView;
           Uri outuri;
         File imgdir;
        private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
       Bitmap bitmap;
       File imagename;
       private TessBaseAPI vinodtessbaseapi;
       // String lang = "eng";
        String path;
        File DATA_PATH;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/VinodOCR";
       // path = getFilesDir()+"/VinodOCR/tessdata";
        checkFile(new File(path+"tessdata/"));
        String lang = "eng";
        vinodtessbaseapi = new TessBaseAPI();
        vinodtessbaseapi.init(path,lang);

    }

    public void imageok(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        imgdir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "VinodOCR/imgs");
        imgdir.mkdirs();
        imagename = new File(imgdir, "Vinod_" + timestamp + ".jpg");
        outuri = Uri.fromFile(imagename);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outuri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved in directory",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

      @Override
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        }

    }

    protected void onPhotoTaken() {

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/VinodOCR/imgs"+imagename, options);

        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/VinodOCR/imgs"+imagename));
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);


            Toast.makeText(this, "Orient", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int rotate = 0;

            switch (exifOrientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
            }

            // Log.v(TAG, "Rotation: " + rotate);

            if (rotate != 0) {

                // Getting width & height of the given image.
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();

                // Setting pre rotate
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.preRotate(rotate);

                // Rotating Bitmap
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
            }

            // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't correct orientation:" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    private  void  checkFile(File dir){
        if(!dir.exists()&&dir.mkdirs()){
            copyFile();

        }
        if(dir.exists()){
            String dfpath = DATA_PATH+"/tessdata/eng.traineddata";
            File datafile = new File(dfpath);
            if(!datafile.exists()){
                copyFile();
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(){
        try {
            String filepath = DATA_PATH+"/tessdata/eng.traineddata";
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("tessdata/eng.traineddata");
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int reads;
            while ((reads = inputStream.read(buffer))!= -1){
                outputStream.write(buffer,0,reads);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void processImage(View view){
        vinodtessbaseapi.setImage(bitmap);
        String OCRResult = vinodtessbaseapi.getUTF8Text();
      //  TextView ocrtextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.OCRTextView);
        editText.setText(OCRResult);
    }


}
```

I am attaching the error log also. Kindly please help me to get rid of this error:

[image]